# How to prevent changed UUIDs when importing CSV files to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am importing a csv file to MongoDB.  The first column is a UUID field.  These UUIDs have already been generated using the [SQL Server unique identifier data-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

For example, a UUID that I wish to import appears in the CSV file as

```
f5d7a927-b03b-4d25-b729-3b13e8a5aed3
```

After importing it to a document in MongoDB, I need it to appear as

```
id: UUID("f5d7a927-b03b-4d25-b729-3b13e8a5aed3")
```

The problem that is that when I do the import, it instead appears as:

```
_id UUID('66356437-6139-3237-2d62-3033622d3464')
```

So I'm guessing that MongoDB is not treating my original UUID as a UUID, but instead as a string basis for the generation of a another UUID?  How can I prevent this?  In my C# application that generates one UUID at a time, it uses the [GuidRepresentation.Standard](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_GuidRepresentation.htm) GUID representation to preserve the UUID when saving to the database.  But I cannot seem to use this when importing pre-existing guids from a csv.

For some added information I am using [MongoDb Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) and selecting the data-type UUID for this field during the csv import configuration.

So to summarize, how can I preserve the UUID in my csv file when I import it to MongoDB?

Comment: Where does compass describe uuid import in their documentation?

Comment: @D.SM I've been looking all around their docs and there doesn't seem to be any specific mention of it.  They just give you the choice of using 'UUID' as a data-type for a csv column when you use their import wizard